# Missing VCOMP120.dll while VCOMP140.dll exists in C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to run some program via VS2017. The program was successfully built but an error popped up when it started to run

> the code execution cannot proceed because VCOMP120.DLL was not found.

I looked up in both `C:\Windows\System32\` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\` and found `VCOMP140.DLL` exists in both directories.

I don't understand why VS tried to search for `VCOMP120.dll` instead of `VCOMP140.dll`. Does this caused by wrong project properties or the installation of VS (I'm using a new OS)?

I'm using Windows 10 Education build 1809 and VS2017.

Comment: If I have my Visual Studio version numbers right, you need to install the [Visual Studio 2013 runtime libraries](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40784).

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the suggestion. So what I consider is that I'm using VS2017, then I don't need to install other versions as long as I'm not doing those development, because the new version should also work. Doesn't installing multiple versions messes up the environment?

Comment: You are probably using a library that was built with an old version of VS, VS2013 to be specific.  Rebuilding it with the VS2017 toolset is highly recommended, having more than one copy of these runtime DLLs in a process can be quite troublesome beyond not finding the file.

Comment: Yes. Ignore me.  Somehow I missed that point and thought you were just running old code.The odds are stacked against a 2013 library working as intended called from 2017 code. There are no guarantees that `std::string`, for example, looks the same in 2017 as it did in 2013, resulting in mystery bugs galore.